# Extract data from specific place irrespective of whitespace

Tags: python, regex

I have a file with hundreds of line of similar patterns. Every line is of the form:

> (msg:"DoS"; flow:to_server,established; content:"|FF FF FF FF FF FF|"; fast_pattern:only; metadata:ruleset community; reference:bugtraq,2347; reference:cve,2001-0144; reference:cve,2001-0572; classtype:shellcode-detect; sid:1326; rev:13;)

I would like to extract whatever is mentioned as **content** in every line. So from above example I want to extract:

> FF FF FF FF FF FF

So far I have this regex:

> (?:content):"(\S+)"

but this will only work when there are no white space characters in the matching text. Any help in making a general regex which extracts whatever is inside content irrespective of spaces ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?<=content:"\|)([^|]+)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iY3eK8/10

Comment: if you use lookbehind, then you don't need to use capturing groups.

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes we dont but OP had used it so put in too.

Comment: It works. But what if I also want to extract the leading and preceding "|" along with the data in between ?

Comment: yes I was about to take it out since I figured it out myself. Thanks for the quick help. I will go ahead and do more reading on regex

Comment: One final idea would be to generalize it along the starting and ending '"'. So instead of matching along '|' we extract whatever is inside the starting and ending ", e.g, content:" ***** " so we extract whatever ****** is. How would you suggest to go about it?